# Recommended .NET Class for a collection of unique integers?

Tags: c#, .net

What would you recommend for class that needs to keep a list of unique integers?

I'm going to want to Add() integers to the collection and also check for existence e.g. Contains().

Would be nice to also get them in a list as a string for display, ie. "1, 5, 10, 21".

Comment: Sorry I didn't specify.  I can use the latest framework.  3.5  but your answers may help others not able to use the latest.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[HashSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx):

> The `HashSet<T>` class provides high-performance set operations. A set is a collection that contains no duplicate elements, and whose elements are in no particular order...
>
> The capacity of a `HashSet<T>` object is the number of elements that the object can hold. A `HashSet<T>` object's capacity automatically increases as elements are added to the object.
>
> The `HashSet<T>` class is based on the model of mathematical sets and provides high-performance set operations similar to accessing the keys of the [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) or [`Hashtable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.aspx) collections. In simple terms, the `HashSet<T>` class can be thought of as a [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) collection without values.
>
> A `HashSet<T>` collection is not sorted and cannot contain duplicate elements...

Comment: I looked at the arraylist and it is certainly better than arraylist, so I removed my previous answer.

Comment: HashSet is going to ToString the type ... not a list.  And the list that he is displaying is one of order, that HashSet doesn't support.

Comment: Correct.  To get the string list, you would use code like:
            int[] a = h.ToArray<int>();
            Array.Sort<int>(a);
            string.Join(', ', a);
This is not high performance, but I get the impression it's not a common operation, and is more for debugging/viewing than computation.

Comment: Updated for Linq: `String.Join(", ", a.OrderBy(_ => _))`.

Comment: @EBGreen literally every other collection type is better than ArrayList for the vast majority of use cases.

Answer (score 3):

In my testing, I have found that a Dictionary with a dummy value is faster than a HashSet, when dealing with very large sets of data (100,000+ in my case). I expect this is because the Dictionary allows you to set an initial capacity, but I don't really know. In the case you're describing, I would probably use the Dictionary if I was expecting a very large set of numbers, and then (or as I was adding to the Dictionary, depending on the intent) iterate over it using a string builder, to create the output string.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't use .NET 3.5, then you can't use HashSet.  If that's the case, it's easy to roll your own based on the Dictionary structure.

```
public class Set<T> {
    private class Unit { ... no behavior }
    private Dictionary<T, Unit> d;

....
}
```

Unit is intended to be a type with exactly one value.  It doesn't matter what you map elements *to*, just use the keys to know what's in your set.  The operations you asked for in the question are straightforward to implement.

Comment: Why even create `Unit` classes? The value can be `null`.

Comment: What would the type be?  "object"?

Answer (score 1):

you could inherit a class from KeyedCollection. This way your key can be the value itself, you can override the ToString so that you get your desired output. This could give you the behaviour you want/need.

Note, this answer was for the framework 2.0 part of the Q