# C#: Most elegant way to test if int x is element of a given set?

Tags: c#, .net, coding-style

Problem: Test if x ∉ { 2, 3, 61, 71 }

I often wondered if there is not a better way than:

```
if (x != 2 && x != 3 && x != 61 && x != 71)
{
  // do things
}
```

and

```
if (!new List<int>{ 2, 3, 61, 71 }.Contains(x))
{
  // do things
}
```

The latter one seems quite elegant, but actually it is kind of irritating if you read it, especially because of the inversion. It's kind of an ugly thing because in English we say *"x is not element of ..."*, which is hard to express in C# without irritating overhead. Maybe one coud say `if (Object(x).IsElementOf(new[] { ... }))` or so?

Hmm.. any suggestions? Are there any .Net standard methods to test things like that?

Comment: This is a duplicate but I'm having a bit of trouble finding the other question myself...

Comment: I can't vote to close, ran out, but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/163732/recommended-net-class-for-a-collection-of-unique-integers

Comment: @Efrain, did you mean `&&` instead of `||`? The two code snippets don't do the same thing...

Comment: I'm not a C# developer, but I am certainly more attracted to the simple approach you're trying to avoid than any of the others listed. I really don't understand why any of the others could be 'better'. They require more code, more instructions, and a loop when one is not necessary.

Comment: @Efrain That edit you just did does not make sense. The if-statement as posted now doesn't make sense since a number will be different from *one* of them when using `||`, hence the comment and edit. As such, your question is now back to not making sense. I'm rolling it back. If you *really* mean to use OR, please consider just deleting the question instead since it is clearly wrong.

Comment: To be clear: `if (x != 2 || x != 3)` will *always* be true, since any value will be different from one of them or both. If you can think of any way where a number will be equal to *both* 2 and 3 *at the same time* so that this returns false, please explain.

Comment: thank you. "v_v .. obviously, yes.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I use an extension method:

```
using System.Linq;

...

public static bool In<T>(this T item, params T[] list)
{
    return list.Contains(item);
}

...


if (!x.In(2,3,61,71))
...
```

You can rename it to `IsElementOf` if you prefer this name...

Comment: Note for people who may wonder, the `Contains` method on the array is supplied by the LINQ namespaces.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth, good point, thanks. I added the necessary using clause to make it clear

Comment: No problem, +1 either way for a very cute snippet.  I'm not ashamed to admit I'm likely to plagiarise that in future :-)

Comment: <micro-optimisation>If this method is intended to be used a lot and/or against a large number of elements then you might get a slight perf improvement by using `Array.IndexOf(list, item) != -1` internally rather than LINQ's `Contains` method.</micro-optimisation>

Comment: @LukeH, you're right, it would be more efficient. However I wouldn't expect this method to be used against a large number of elements, so it would probably not make a noticeable difference...

Comment: @ThomasLevesque I liked your solution. But I feel this is a violation of OOP principle. I feel that it is not the duty of int to know if it is present in a list.

Comment: This sort of stuff should come with a sexual content warning. Beautiful stuff!

Comment: @LukeH <nitpicking>If optimization were of the essence, it would be best to simply stick with the ugly (x != 2 && x != 3 && x != 61 && x != 71) and altogether avoid the overhead of calling a function and building a throw-away list.</nitpicking>

Answer (score 15):

Old question, but haven't seen this simple answer:

```
!new []{2, 3, 61, 71}.Contains(x)
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use following LinQ method:

```
var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var number = 3;

if (list.Any(item => item == number))
    //number is in the list
```

And for the readability you can put it in an extension method:

```
public static bool IsElementOf(this int n, IEnumerable<int> list)
{
    return list.Any(i => n == i);
}

//usage
if(3.IsElementOf(list)) //in the list
```

Answer (score 3):

Starting with C# 9 version, you can use logical patterns too.

```
if (x is not (2 or 3 or 61 or 71))
{
    // do things
}
```

Answer (score 2):

what about

```
if(new[] { 2, 3, 61, 71 }.Except(x).FirstOrDefault() != 0)
{
   ...
}
```

or something on those lines?

Answer (score 1):

it turns out that 2, 3, 61, and 71 are prime. so, modulo your number into 25986 (= 2 * 3 * 61 * 71). If the result is non-zero, then continue with the if block.

```
if ((x < 2) || (25968 % x != 0))
{ /* do all the stuff */ }
```

I would strongly advise heavily commenting this technique in the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
var list=CreateNewList(); //returns your list of elements
var element=GetElement(); //returns an element that might be in the list
if(list.Any(x=>x.Equals(element))
{
  //do something
}
```

It's still inverted from what you're used to but it's more expressive (if the list has any value that equals element).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you meant && and not ||, you can just write a func and use that throughout your code. You can shorten the new[] part since the type (int) is infered by the in paramter of the func.

```
Func<int, bool> IsSafe = x => !new[] { 2, 3, 61, 71 }.Contains(x);

Console.WriteLine(IsSafe(68)); // is true
Console.WriteLine(IsSafe(2));  // is false
```